# Why does ajax accordian change the ID of dynamic controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, accordion

I create an accordian with a panel that looks like this.

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server" HeaderCssClass="spitter_"
            HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected"
            ContentCssClass="accordionContent" runat="server"
            SelectedIndex="0" FadeTransitions="false"
             TransitionDuration="250"
            FramesPerSecond="30"
            RequireOpenedPane="false" AutoSize="None">
            <Panes>
                <asp:AccordionPane ID="AccPane1" runat="server">
                    <Header>
                        My header
                    </Header>
                    <Content>
                        <asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                    </Content>
                </asp:AccordionPane>
```

which works perfectly. Although, the controls i make inside the accordian obtain an ID different to what i specify.Please note that the controls get made perfectly.

I give it the ID of

```
check_box.ID = "check_box" + i.ToString();
```

where i is a value in a loop.
Instead of having an ID of "check_box1" or "check_box2" i get an ID of "AccordianPane_check_box1"

Heres where i initiate the checkboxes..

```
     for (int i = 0; i < depts.Count; i++)
        {
            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            TableCell dept_ = new TableCell();
            TableCell check_row = new TableCell();
            row.ID = "row_" + i.ToString();
            CheckBox mark_row = new CheckBox();
            mark_row.ID = "check_box" + i.ToString();                
            check_row.Controls.Add(mark_row);              

            row.Cells.Add(check_row);
            row.Cells.Add(dept_);
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
panel1.Controls.Add(table);
```

Any help with this would be great.

Comment: This is how webforms work.

Comment: I understand that. What concerns me is that, I specify an ID to a control. And that ID gets altered. Why do i specify the ID of an element if its going to change beyond my will.

Comment: Set ClientIDMode to "Static". Check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks malkam. can you post that as an answer so that i can mark it?

Comment: The ID gets altered because, for example, there might be a nested user control with elements with the same ID. Static ClientIDMode is a good solution if you never encounter this situation.